# Angular - TypeError: Cannot read property 'jobTitle' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms, angular-validation

I am building a `Angular7` app implementing `ReactiveForms` Validation I am putting my validation messages & their display control all in `component.ts`

create-job.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-create-job',
 templateUrl: './create-job.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./create-job.component.css']
})

export class CreateJobComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

jobForm = this.fb.group({
 jobTitle: ['', Validators.required]
});

formError: {
'jobTitle': ''
};
validationMessages = {
 jobTitle: {
  required: 'Job Title required'
}};


ngOnInit() {
 this.jobForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
  this.logValidationError(this.jobForm);
 });}


logValidationError(group: FormGroup): void {
Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
  const abstractControl = group.get(key);
  if (abstractControl instanceof FormGroup) {
    this.logValidationError(abstractControl);
  } else {
    if (abstractControl && !abstractControl.valid) {
      const messages = this.validationMessages[key];
      console.log(messages);
      console.log(abstractControl.errors);
      for (const errorkey in abstractControl.errors) {
        if (errorkey) {
          this.formError[key] += messages[errorkey] + ' ';
        }
      }
    }
  }});}}


interface IJob {
jobTitle: string;
jobDesc: string;
}
```

create-job.component.html

```
<div class="row" [formGroup]="jobForm">
<div class="form-group"
[ngClass]="{'has-error': jobForm.get('jobTitle').errors && (jobForm.get('jobTitle').touched || jobForm.get('jobTitle').dirty)  }">
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="jobTitle" />

 <span class="help-block" *ngIf="formError">
  {{ formError.jobTitle }}
</span>
```

Create

But this is throwing the below error.

[image]

How to get rid of this error & display the validation error message ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="help-block" *ngIf="formError">
   {{ jobForm.jobTitle }}
</span>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.jobForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
  this.logValidationError(this.jobForm);
 });}


logValidationError(group: FormGroup): void {
//...
```

Since `logValidationError` is not an arrow function, I believe that inside the subscriber it won't have access to the `this` context of the component. Change the declaration to

```
logValidationError = (group: FormGroup) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getter.

```html
jobForm : FormGroup ;

get jobTitle() { return this.jobForm.get( 'jobTitle' ); }
```

this part should be in the cycle **ngOnInit**

```html
this.jobForm = this.fb.group({
 jobTitle: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the issue.

Cause: formError was not getting initialized & while access formError[key] it was throwing the error.

Fix: Moved the jobForm & formError inside ngOnInit

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


export class CreateJobComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

 jobForm: FormGroup;
 formError: any;
 validationMessages = {
 jobTitle: {
  required: 'Job Title required'
}};


ngOnInit() {
 this.jobForm = this.fb.group({
  jobTitle: ['', Validators.required]
});
 this.formError = {
  jobTitle: ''
};
this.jobForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
  this.logValidationError(this.jobForm);
});}



 logValidationError = (group: FormGroup): void => {
  this.formError = {
  jobTitle: ''
 };
 Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
  const abstractControl = group.get(key);
  if (abstractControl instanceof FormGroup) {
    this.logValidationError(abstractControl);
  } else {
    if (abstractControl && !abstractControl.valid) {
      const messages = this.validationMessages[key];

      for (const errorkey in abstractControl.errors) {
        if (errorkey) {
          console.log(this.formError);
          this.formError[key] += messages[errorkey] + ' ';
        }
      }
    }
   }});}}
```